# How to name a method that has an out parameter?

Tags: naming-conventions, parameters, return, out

What is the common preference to name a method that has an out parameter inside?

Usually I use Get as a prefix to mention that the method returns a value (like GetMyBusiness).

But what if there is an out parameter that will be set after the method call?
Should the method name mention this and focus only the return value?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard in nomenclature.  However, if your method is going to be acting on compound types, consider adopting a convention of using Get...And...() to indicate that there are two things going on.  For example:

```
int GetPopulationAndMeanAge(out double meanAge)
{
    // ...
    meanAge = CalculateMeanAge();
    return totalPopulation;
}
```

I think the better approach is to return a compound type instead.  In a garbage collected language, there is really no excuse **NOT** to do this, except in cases where such a method is called, say, millions of times and instrumentation reveals that the GC isn't properly handling the load.  In non-GC languages, it presents a minor issue in terms of making sure that it's clear who is responsible for cleaning up the memory when you're done.

Refactoring the previous into a compound type (C#):

```
public class PopulationStatistics {
    int Population { get; set; }
    double MeanAge { get; set; }
}


PopulationStatistics GetPopulationStatistics()
{
    // ...
    return new PopulationStatistics { Population = totalPopulation, MeanAge = CalculateMeanAge };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method name should describe the function of the method (self-documenting code).  If the method signature will indicate that it uses an out parameter, the signature should be sufficient to alert developers that a value will be returned in the variable.  I would consider it to be redundant, therefore, to include this in the method name.  Even self-documenting code should be clear and concise.   If your language doesn't make this clear then I would either document it in the name, if it can be done clearly and concisely, or using inline comments.

Answer (score 0):

Why not return that parameter instead?

Anyway, you could use "modify" or "handle" prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say in this case it's more important to keep your naming *consistent* rather than what your naming scheme actually is.  It makes things easier for those who code behind you, since they will know what to expect from your methods based on how they're named.

Having said that, `Get` should be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the language.
In C#, for example, there's no need to add it to the name of the function, it's already in the signature: you cannot call the function without specifying `out` again, so there's no risk of missing the side effect:

```
Int32.TryParse("123", out number);
```

Comment: But here, you have no clue if this returns a bool or not. word "try" might be a clue though. when you try something, either you succeed or you fail so naturally you may expect the bool value.

Comment: @Burak: Intellisense will tell you what it returns.  You are only a couple of steps from calling it this TakeStringAndTryToConvertItToANumberReturningTheNumberAsAnOutParamAndBoolOfIfItWorked()

Comment: That's true - but this is descriptive. The function *tries to parse* - good name. However, the name alone has no indication the function has an out parameter, that would create redundancy, as the signature already has that.

Comment: I think if a method process is a kind of attempt and the return value is pointing that with a boolean, Try is really a good candidate as a prefix.

And if the method seems like it might have more than one out parameters, it can be good to create a method parameter object and return that with a method name starting with Get. See plinth's answer to this question.